# Evaluating Surface Integral Using Stokes' Theorem

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Let $\vec{F}$ be the vector field $\vec{F}\left(x,y,z\right)=\left(z,x,y\right)$. Let $\rm S$ be portion
of the surface $x^{2}+y^{2}+z=1$ lying above the $\rm XY$-plane, oriented upward. Evaluate the surface integral

$$\int_{\rm S}{\rm Curl}\vec{F}\cdot\vec{{\rm d}S}$$

I know how to evaluate the surface integral directly, but I don't know how to apply Stokes' theorem to solve it. Can someone please walk me through this? Thank you for your help!

Comment: What have you tried? The theorem is very explicit
$$\int_{\rm S}\left(\vec{\nabla}\times\vec{F}\right)\cdot\vec{{\rm d}S}=\int_{\partial {\rm S}}\vec{F}\cdot\vec{{\rm d}\ell}$$
Do you see what $\partial{\rm S}$ is?

Comment: Not really, I tried doing it but the computation was very similar to direct evaluation, so I wasn't sure if I was doing it right.

Comment: The computation is pretty simple, so don't think you are doing wrong if your solution seems to be too simple. It will be easier for us to help you if you show us your way of thinking. So add your trial!

Comment: Can you show the computation so I can check it please? I have it on paper and it's really messy.

Comment: It is far better correcting your own solution rather than reading the solutions of others. So take a couple of minutes and write it down. Then I can point out your mistake, and post an answer.

Comment: Okay. When it says above the xy-plane, does that mean above z=0?

Comment: Exactly, it means $z>0$. See here http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=x%5E2%2By%5E2%2Bz%3D1.

Comment: Okay, so when I plug in the components of the parameterization into the vector field, which are costi + sintj + k, should I end up with (0, costi, sintj)?

Comment: I understand you try to parameterize a circle (which is true), so you took $x=\cos\theta,\: y=\sin\theta,\: z=0$ and got that $\vec{F}=\begin{pmatrix}0\\\cos\theta\\\sin\theta\end{pmatrix}$ as you should.

Comment: But my integral ends up being (0,-sintcost, sintcost). How would I integrate with the commas?

Comment: No. You have a line integral over a vector field. See here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Line_integral#Line_integral_of_a_vector_field.

Comment: Then how would I evaluate the line integral?

Comment: As you usually do. I can't teach you how to calculate line integrals. If you don't know that, you should read some first. See this https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1742979/evaluate-the-following-line-integral as an example of a calculation.

Answer (score 1):

It's actually pretty straightforward. Let the parametrization of the circle $x^2+y^2=1$ laying on the $xy$ plane be $\gamma(t)=(\cos t,\sin t,0)$, where $t\in[0,2\pi]$. Then $\gamma'(t)=(-\sin t, \cos t,0)$ and

\begin{align}
\int_{\rm S}{\rm Curl}\vec{F}\cdot\vec{{\rm d}S}
=\int_{0}^{2\pi} f(\gamma(t))\cdot\gamma'(t){\rm d}t
=\int_{0}^{2\pi} (0,\cos t,\sin t)\cdot(-\sin t,\cos t,0){\rm d}t
=\int_{0}^{2\pi} (\cos t)^2{\rm d}t
\end{align}